# Where is the arm interrupt handler for linux?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm looking through the [source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel) but I can't find where the low level asm `interrupt_vector` and `fast_interrupt_vector` code is or where the higher level C code called by low level vectors is. Where is the interrupt code for arm at?

Comment: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#L1086

Answer (score 0):

The interrupt handlers are in the device driver code. Each device type has its own driver somewhere in the `driver` subdirectory. The driver initialization code typically requests an irq from the kernel, passing a function pointer to the handler as a parameter. This means that the service routines are not collected together, but are essentially "all over the place".

Comment: But isn't there still a single low level entry point for the `interrupt_vector` and `fast_interrupt_vector`? Something has to be called before all the driver code can be called?